# Yocto: Where is the source for my project?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

I recently discovered [Yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org/). I'm able to successfully build an image using the command `bitbake fsl-image-gui`. But now, I would like to browse the code, the project specific code and the Kernel code for the `fsl-image-gui` but I cannot figure how ?

Where is the source code when I build my Yocto project and how could I browse it ?

Comment: Have you looked at the [slides](http://free-electrons.com/training/yocto/) provided by Free Electrons?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two halves of the Yocto setup:

1. The `sources/` directory, containing the bitbake recipes and supporting configuration, and
2. The `build/` directory, where the actual builds take place.

Each of the bitbake recipes (i.e. `*.bb` files found in a structure under the `sources/` directory) that you run should be constrained to a directory structure like:

```
build/
   tmp/
      work/
         < platform name >/
             < recipe name >/
                 < version >/
                     ...juicy stuff here...
```

Underneath the `< version >/` directory, you should find a structure like:

```
build/
image/
package/
packages-split/
temp/
your_unpacked_source_directory/
...and others
```

...where `your_unpacked_source_directory` is determined by the directory structure contained in the downloaded and unpacked source. (e.g. as contained in the `.tgz` file)

All of the build logs and scripts generated during the build are contained in the `temp/` directory.

The `package/` directory contains all of the files that are to be packaged as a result of this recipe. The `packages-split/` divides the files into their separate packages, e.g. base package, `-dev` package, `-dbg` package, `-staticdev` package.

Answer (score -2):

Well, have you looked around in the build tree?

You'll have a `downloads` directory, in which all downloaded tarballs are stored, as well as all cloned repositories.

The actual unpacking and building takes place in subdirectories under `build/tmp/work/<arch>/`.